# How can i rotate the video orientation programatically by using videoview in android?

Tags: android, rotation, android-videoview

I trimmed the Portrait video by using Mp4 parser, it trimmed and the video orientation changes to 90 degrees. How can I rotate the video orientation?

Comment: you could also rotate the videoView using setRotation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion but if i give the rotation of 90 degrees to videoview it is appearing black screen (but the audio is audible)..